# jQuery/PHP Shopping Script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, store, cart

Does anyone know where I may find a really simple easy jQuery and PHP Shopping Cart, where it simply redirects users to a PayPal payment option? No logging in?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know any with jQuery and PHP but I know it can be done using ye' ol' <form> element and bunch of inputs https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/dmo/demo_wa_1-outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/Quick-ECommerce-with-PHP-and-PayPal/1/) and [this](http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/276/)